# Can I land in Dublin and drive up to start my worker visa in Northern Ireland?

Tags: visas, uk

I am an American moving to Northern Ireland on a Tier 2 visa. On our official move date, do I need to land in Northern Ireland (UK) or can I land in Dublin and drive up?

My concern is getting through Irish immigration and also not having an official 'start day' stamped on my passport for my tier 2. No border = No stamp/official start date, right?

Comment: Thus is a great question for [Expatriates.SE].  Unfortunately it is off topic here.

Comment: I'm not sure it is an Expatriates question.  He's basically asking if he can have a short visit to the Republic before he emigrates to the UK.